# How to add multiple subscription in Azure Logic app Service bus topic trigger

Tags: azure-logic-apps

As I am having a logic app where the trigger is service bus topic subscription. I want to add multiple subscription ("A", "B","C") for the given topic in my logic app service bus topic trigger . Whenever i select topic it only allows me to select single subscription. Is there any way to add multiple subscription from an array or static variables ? if yes then how to add conditions ? I tried  using array, but i have to provide the index of the subscription.

I can use multi trigger logic app for all of the subscriptions to achieve what I am looking for, but is there any other way like using some wildcard characters ***** or **/** or something else which i am not familiar with .

Answer (score 0):

The action supports selecting only one subscription as you have observed.

Multi Trigger Logic App is indeed one way to go about it but note that the designer doesn't support them, and you will be forced to edit only using the code view.

One alternative would be to split your logic app into two

- one for your business logic that is triggered by a HTTP request
- one (or more) that is triggered by the service bus subscription trigger and [calls the first logic app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint)

Another alternative is to leverage the [Event Grid Integration in Service Bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-to-event-grid-integration-concept), ***but*** note that this is currently applicable only for the Premium Tier.

In this approach, the logic app would trigger based on an event message from Event Grid with details of the subscription that has messages ready to process. You would then use the [Get messages from a topic subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/servicebus/#get-messages-from-a-topic-subscription-(peek-lock)) action to fetch the messages to process.